# Macro to print selection of cells from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'd need to click one button in one Excel workbook and automatically opens another workbook from a website and prints a selection of cells from this workbook.

Until now I have the code that opens me the workbook form the website, but I would need to include the part of printing a selection of cells.
Thank you in advance!

Here is the code I have:

```
Sub Project4000()
    'open IE, navigate to the desired page and loop until fully loaded
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    my_url = "Link to the file in the website"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate my_url
        .Top = 50
        .Left = 530
        .Height = 400
        .Width = 400

        Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

    ' Input the userid and password
    IE.Document.getElementById("uid").Value = "user"
    IE.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "passw"

    ' Click the "Search" button
    IE.Document.getElementById("enter").Click

    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You say "*I have the code that opens me the workbook form the website*" is that workbook already opened by that code? Because I can only see that this clicks at a button on a website. To print out a selected range `Workbooks("my_wb_name").Worksheets("my_ws_name").Range("A1:A5").PrintOut` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With the posted code, cliking a buttom, it opens Explorer, access directly to the website with a user and password and opens the Excel Workbook. So I'd like to add to that buttom the printing of a group of cells, in horizontal A4 size.

Comment: As I said `Workbooks("my_wb_name").Worksheets("my_ws_name").Range("A1:A‌​5").PrintOut` should print the range `A1:A‌​5` of the worksheet `my_ws_name` of the workbook `my_wb_name`. Of course you need to replace the name of the workbook and worksheet and also fill in the desired range. You need to put in some effort now.

Comment: By adding only that lineit gives me an error: 2147417848 (80010108).

Comment: After cliking Finish, it opens the file but it doesn't print it... I don't know which is the problem.

Comment: Then you did something wrong. (I can't say anything more because of insufficient information and because you didn't ask a proper question.)

Comment: I only copied the code you told me and changed the workbook and worksheet names, and the cells. Where should I introduce the print code? At the end of my code (just before End Sub)? Thanks

Comment: Make sure the workbook is fully loaded in Excel before you run `.PrintOut`. To make this sure you can `Application.Wait` some seconds before you run `.PrintOut`. Also try to `.Activate` the range you want to print before `.PrintOut`.